# Save a value at closure and restore the value at reopening

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently learning swiftui and have the following problem:

My code contains a timer that counts up when the app is opened. This works fine so far. Now I want the previous time to be saved when the app is closed and when it is reopened, the value is loaded and counted up from there.

Is there a simple way to implement this?

Here my code:

```
struct TimeView: View {

   @State private var timeTracker = 0

   let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

   var body: some View {
       HStack{
           Text("\(timeTracker) s")
       }
       .onReceive(timer) { time in
           self.timeTracker += 1
       }
   }
}

struct TimeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimeView()
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, there is a simple way to save and retrieve your previous time. Look into `UserDefaults` and `@AppStorage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct TimeView: View {

    @State private var timeTracker = 0

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    @AppStorage("TIME") var time: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("\(timeTracker) s")
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in timeTracker += 1 }
        .onAppear(perform: { timeTracker = time })
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in time = timeTracker }
    }
}

//OR

struct TimeView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("TIME") var timeTracker: Int = 0
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("\(timeTracker) s")
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in timeTracker += 1 }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks! Just wondering how would it looks like with the "UserDefault" ?